# How to position the Icon without overflowing? I tried by adding padding, by wrapping widget in flexible, but no luck so far

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

This is the code:

```
Row(
children: [
GestureDetector(
....
child: RoundIconBtnPlus(
          icon: new IconButton(
           icon: new Icon(
           FontAwesome.plus,
                           ),
           iconSize: 30.ssp,
                           )
                         ))])
```

This is where I have declared RoundIconBtnPlus

```
class RoundIconBtnPlus extends StatelessWidget {
  RoundIconBtnPlus({@required this.icon});

  final IconButton icon;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawMaterialButton(
      child: IconButton(
        icon: new Icon(
            FontAwesome.plus,
            color: Colors.white
        ),
      ),
      shape: CircleBorder(),
      fillColor: HexColor("#4c4f5e"),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the error I got:
[image: Plus Button]

Error code

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 21 pixels on the right.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Row file:///C:/app_name/lib/ui_screen/HomeScreen.dart:147:35
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.horizontal.
The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#30a0f relayoutBoundary=up1 OVERFLOWING:
  needs compositing
  creator: Row ← Column ← DecoratedBox ← ConstrainedBox ← Padding ← Container ← Padding ← Row ← Column
    ← Row ← ConstrainedBox ← Container ← ⋯
  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 76.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=154.8, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: Size(154.8, 48.0)
  direction: horizontal
  mainAxisAlignment: start
  mainAxisSize: max
  crossAxisAlignment: center
  textDirection: ltr
  verticalDirection: down
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 21 pixels on the right.
```

I tried wrapping RoundIconBtnPlus in a flexible widget and I also tried adding padding to IconButton and RoundIconBtnPlus, toggled with mainAxisAlignment property but no luck so far. Please look into it.

Comment: did u used `Positioned` widget with `Stack` ?

Comment: no I am not using Stack, as I don't have much knowledge about it. @theiskaa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example on how to do it :

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Column(children: [
      Text("Age"),
      Text("20"),
      Row(children: [
        Flexible(child: _iconButton()),
        Flexible(child: _iconButton()),
      ])
    ]), color: Colors.green, width: 100);
  }

  Widget _iconButton() {
    return RawMaterialButton(
        child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
        ),
        shape: CircleBorder(),
        fillColor: Colors.red,
        onPressed: () {
          print("onPressed");
        });
  }
}
```

The key is to wrap the direct children of the Row widget in Flexible (or Expanded) widgets.

You should also use the onPressed property of the IconButton (and you probably don't need to add a GestureDetector above), but I guess that your RoundIconBtnPlus Widget is not finished.

Comment: GestureDetector is needed as I am using OnTapUp and onTapDown.

Answer (score 0):

This is the layout I think you are trying to make. the red one is the Row that hosts the 2 buttons. to align and justify the children inside your row widget you can use,

```
mainAxisAligment: MainAxisAligment.spaceEvenly,
```

there are other aligment types such as, spaceBetween, start, end,center.

this layout is,

```
Container->Colum [Text, Text, Row[child,child]]
```

[image: Widget Layout]

Comment: No luck.. same problem. I gave mainAxisAlignment at both column level and row level, and only at column level and only at row level but the same probelm exists.

Comment: yea tried crossaxis property still the same. got the resolution, wrapped the gesturedetectors in flexible, now it's working fine